# Shell script to copy files from one location to another location and rename add the current date and time stamp to every file in YYYYMMDDHHmmSSformat

Tags: xml, bash, shell, sh

I need to copy a file from one location to another while renaming the file with adding date and time stamp `YYYYMMDDHHmmSS` in this Format only using shell.

My Bash shell code:

```
cd $1
f1=Sup_Org_File_
for f in *.xml
do 
   cp -v "$f" $2/"${f1%}"$(date +%F%H:%M).xml
   cp -v "$f" $3/"${f1%}"$(date +%F%H:%M).xml
done
```

Comment: Why do you copy twice? What should `$2` and `$3` contain? You'll want to quote them both, and `$1` too; see [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: What is the purpose of `%` in `${f1%}` ?

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps you

**for Bash shell Script**

```
cd path_to_file
for f in *.xml
do 
   cp -v "$f" path_to_copy_file/"${f%.xml}"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).xml
done
```

Comment: I need for Bash shell script.. In the this YYYYMMDDHHmmSS . I tried what you suggested its not getting date and time stamp in expected format..

Comment: edited this will give results in the expected format. Does this help??

Answer (score 1):

Just `"${f1%}"` doesn't do anything useful; you want to put a pattern for something to actually remove after the `%`; and of course you probably want to remove a suffix from `f`, not from `f1`. (Giving your variables sensible names also helps.)

It's not clear what you expect `$2` and `$3` to contain, but they probably won't work correctly after you `cd $1` (and all three of these should be quoted anyway).

Guessing a bit as to what you actually want, try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
d=$(date +'%F%H:%M)
for f in "$1"/*.xml
do
    # Trim directory prefix
    b=${f#$1/}
    # Trim .xml suffix
    b=${b%.xml}
    # Copy
    cp -v "$f" "$2/$b$d".xml
    cp -v "$f" "$3/$b$d".xml
done
```

There are no Bashisms here so I put a `/bin/sh` shebang on this.